# ruby rails converting params to int array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am sending data via get and I need to put it into a int array to be used in a find.
here is my code :

```
@found = Array.new
  params['candidate'].each do |c|
  @found << c.to_i
  end
```

My url looks like this

```
http://localhost:3000/export/candidate?candidate[]=3&candidate[]=4&commit=Export
```

If it makes any difference I am using it for this find

```
@candidate = Candidate.find(:all, :conditions => ["candidates.id IN ?", @found])
```

But currently it doesn't put it in a real array because I get this error

```
Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '4)' at line 1: SELECT * FROM `candidates` WHERE (candidates.id IN 4,2)
```

The brackets are missing around the array

Thanks and good morning!

Alex

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just put parentheses around your ?

```
@candidate = Candidate.find(:all, :conditions => ["candidates.id IN (?)", @found])
```

Also, your first snippet can be collapsed down to:

```
@found = params['candidate'].map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

what does this mean &: ?

Comment: It's an easy way of passing a block which just calls the given method on the argument passed into the block. There's a good explanation at http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html

Comment: it seems .map is quite useful

Answer (score 1):

The entire conversion you are making is unnecessary. You can pass the string array as a input to the query (as long as the string values represent numbers).

You can get what you need in one line:

```
Candidate.find_all_by_id(params[`candidate`])
```

Which is same as:

```
Candidate.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => params[`candidate`]})
```

Which is same as:

```
Candidate.find(:all, :conditions => ["id IN (?)",params[`candidate`]])
```

Your original attempt did not work because you did not put brackets after the `IN` clause.